# When can we omit the preposition "on" before weekdays

Tags: prepositions, american-english, prepositional-phrases, time

I am a bit confused. When can we omit the preposition *on* before weekdays? (Monday, Tuesday etc.) Sometimes I read weekdays without the preposition *on*. If the preposition is left out, does it work the same way, or does it change the meaning?

**Example without the preposition**

> The UGC issued the public notice **Monday** after its two previous orders
>   in this regard were overlooked by the DU.

**Example with the preposition**

> The commission **on Monday** also issued a public notice against the FYUP
>   in all leading newspapers for parents and students.

Comment: Personally, I find the example without the preposition awkward. Is this a regional variation, perhaps?

Comment: You can avoid it when you're in the U.S.A.

Comment: Again in the USA, I think using "on" is the proper form, though both are commonly used. When I think about where I have heard it with no preposition, it is in narrations such as the TV or radio news.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! Yes, it was from a news website. So we should not avoid the preposition "on" before weekdays?

Comment: @ user62015: Unless you're sure of your exact context, it's safest to stick with ***on** [weekday]*. Dropping the preposition is an informal usage that won't necessarily sound "natural" in all contexts anyway, apart from the fact that it's simply the wrong ["register"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)) for most formal contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you so much! I am done now. This website is an awesome and perfect place to get help!!!

Comment: user62015 I think there's more to be said about this topic. Please check back over the next few days to see some full Answers provided by people with various perspectives.

Comment: Sounds marked (and more likely to be American) to me.

Answer (score 5):

From the context, it seems likely that omitting "on" was a journalistic decision.

The *Associated Press Stye Book,* used by journalists and others when writing public press releases, considers "on" before a day/date to be unnecessary, and therefore a waste of space in print. Omitting it is a habit that's a throwback to pre-internet days when paper size mattered :)

A journalist following AP Style might write:

> "The event happened here Tuesday, in response to the other event that
>   occurred June 10."

Both the preposition "on" and the "th" from "10th" are omitted to save space.

In spoken conversation or non-journalistic writing, people typically include "on," even though it's not required for meaning.

Comment: +1. Also, I can't think of any time when it's wrong to put in the *on*, so if you're ever unsure, just use it, as FumbleFingers said in the comments above.